# Regex that disallows double underscore, except it is at the end of the word followed by 'x' symbol

Tags: javascript, regex

I need a regex that disallows double underscore in the word, but with a one exemption: if it is at the end and followed by x - then string is valid. Symbols order doesn't play role.
For example:

```
Foo_bar__x = VALID
Foo__bar_x = INVALID
```

A string can contain more than one single underscore, and alphanumeric symbols. Here is regex that almost suits my requirements , it makes "__" forbidden, but it doesn't handle the case with __x ending:

```
^(?!.*__.*)\w+$
```

Comment: ^([^\s\_]+_?)+__X$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this regex with negative lookahead:

```
/^(?!.*__(?!x$))\w+$/
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZgZfyu/2)

`(?!.*__(?!x))` is a negative lookahead that asserts failure when we get `__` that is followed by any character other than `x` at the end of input.

Nested negative lookahead `(?!x$)` is for asserting double underscores are not followed by `x` before end to get a successful match.

Comment: It shouldn't work for the case Foo__x_bar , but it does

Comment: I mistyped x with c

Comment: Foo_bar___x should match as it ends with __x but isn't matching. Am I missing something?

Comment: Fortunately it is not required

Comment: @PushpeshKumarRajwanshi: Not for this requirement but for academic interest you can use `/^(?!.*__(?!_*x$))\w+$/`

Comment: Looks like this regex also matches OP's requirements. ^(?=.*__x$)(?!.*__[^x]$).*$  https://regex101.com/r/9Uk2Zg/1 but I liked your nested negative lookahead. Thanks

Comment: @PushpeshKumarRajwanshi I believe `__x` is optional in input. In that case your regex won't match `abcdef`

Comment: Oh yes, I forgot that. In that case nesting will be needed and your regex is perfect.